# I got Malformed config.xml when trying to compile with PhoneGap Build

Tags: xml, cordova

I have search, but I didn't know what was wrong with my config.xml here is the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- config.xml reference: https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml -->
<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id        = "com.techware.callMyCab"
        version   = "1.0.0">


    <name>TaxiRide/name>

    <description>
       TaxiRide is your one stop cab ride
    </description>

    <author href="http://taxiride.com/" email="info@taxiride.com">
        Taxi Ride
    </author>


    <!--
        If you do not want any permissions to be added to your app, add the
        following tag to your config.xml; you will still have the INTERNET
        permission on your app, which PhoneGap requires.
    -->
        <!-- <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-5.2.0" /> -->
        <!-- <preference name="phonegap-version"       value="3.5.0" /> -->
    <preference name="permissions"                value="none"/>

    <!-- Customize your app and platform with the preference element. -->
    <preference name="orientation"                value="portrait" />        <!-- all: default means both landscape and portrait are enabled -->
    <preference name="target-device"              value="universal" />      <!-- all: possible values handset, tablet, or universal -->
    <preference name="fullscreen"                 value="false" />           <!-- all: hides the status bar at the top of the screen -->
    <preference name="webviewbounce"              value="true" />           <!-- ios: control whether the screen 'bounces' when scrolled beyond the top -->
    <preference name="prerendered-icon"           value="true" />           <!-- ios: if icon is prerendered, iOS will not apply it's gloss to the app's icon on the user's home screen -->
    <preference name="stay-in-webview"            value="false" />          <!-- ios: external links should open in the default browser, 'true' would use the webview the app lives in -->
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle"         value="black-opaque" />   <!-- ios: black-translucent will appear black because the PhoneGap webview doesn't go beneath the status bar -->
    <preference name="detect-data-types"          value="true" />           <!-- ios: controls whether data types (such as phone no. and dates) are automatically turned into links by the system -->
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend"            value="false" />          <!-- ios: if set to true, app will terminate when home button is pressed -->

        <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />           <!-- ios: if set to false, the spinner won't appear on the splash screen during app loading -->
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen"    value="false" />           <!-- ios: if set to false, the splash screen must be hidden using a JavaScript API -->
    <preference name="disable-cursor"             value="false" />          <!-- blackberry: prevents a mouse-icon/cursor from being displayed on the app -->
    <preference name="android-installLocation"    value="auto" />           <!-- android: app install location. 'auto' will choose. 'internalOnly' is device memory. 'preferExternal' is SDCard. -->
    <preference name="splashScreenDelay"        value="70000" />
        <!--
        Define a specific version of PhoneGap to build into your app.
        <preference name="phonegap-version"       value="3.5.0" />
    -->

    <!-- Plugins -->

    <!-- Core plugins -->

        <!-- <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation"  source="pgb" version="0.3.7" />
        <gap:plugin name="com.ionic.keyboard" source="pgb" version="1.0.3" />
        <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" source="pgb" version="0.2.12" />
        <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" source="pgb" version="0.3.9" />
        <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" source="pgb" version="0.2.10" />
        <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" source="pgb" version="0.4.6" />
        <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" source="pgb" version="0.5.2" />
        <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" source="pgb" version="0.2.12" />
        <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" source="pgb" version="0.3.4" /> -->

        <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation"  source="npm" spec="~2.4.0"/>
        <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" source="npm"  />
        <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" source="npm" spec="~1.1.3" />
        <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-orientation" source="npm" spec="~1.0.4" />
        <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" source="npm"  spec="~1.3.0" />
        <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" source="npm"  spec="~1.6.0" />
        <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" spec="~1.5.0" />
        <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" source="npm"  spec="~1.3.0" />
        <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" spec="~4.0.0" />

        <!-- <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1.0.0"  /> -->
    <!-- Third party plugins -->
    <!-- A list of available plugins are available at https://build.phonegap.com/plugins -->
    <!--
        <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner" />
    -->

    <!-- Define app icon for each platform. -->
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:qualifier="ldpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:qualifier="mdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:qualifier="hdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png"  gap:platform="android"    gap:qualifier="xhdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png"     gap:platform="blackberry" />
    <icon src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png"     gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover"/>
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="72" height="72" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="114" height="114" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="144" height="144" />
    <icon src="res/icon/webos/icon-64.png"          gap:platform="webos" />
    <icon src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png"  gap:platform="winphone" />
    <icon src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173.png" gap:platform="winphone"   gap:role="background" />

    <!-- Define app splash screen for each platform. -->
        <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" />
        <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png"       gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png"       gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png"       gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png"      gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png"              gap:platform="blackberry" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png"         gap:platform="ios"     width="320" height="480" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png"      gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="960" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="1136" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png"           gap:platform="ios"     width="768" height="1024" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png"          gap:platform="ios"     width="1024" height="768" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg"      gap:platform="winphone" />

    <gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="CFBundleShortVersionString">
    <string>100</string>
    </gap:config-file>

    <!--
        Define access to external domains.
        <access />            - a blank access tag denies access to all external resources.
        <access origin="*" /> - a wildcard access tag allows access to all external resource.
        Otherwise, you can specify specific domains:
        <access origin="http://phonegap.com" />                    - allow any secure requests to http://phonegap.com/
        <access origin="http://phonegap.com" subdomains="true" />  - same as above, but including subdomains, such as http://build.phonegap.com/
        <access origin="http://phonegap.com" browserOnly="true" /> - only allows http://phonegap.com to be opened by the child browser.
    -->

    <access origin="*"/>
    <!-- Added the following intents to support the removal of whitelist code from base cordova to a plugin -->
    <!-- Whitelist configuration. Refer to https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html -->
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>

</widget>
```

If I try to compile it using PhoneGap Build I get a malformed config.xml error. I got the code from documents so I'm really not sure what the problem can be.

Comment: Sorry, this is not how StackOverflow works.  Questions of the form _"Here's a bunch of my code, it doesn't work, can someone help me figure it out"_ are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask] for more information, and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157)

Comment: Thanks for you response, please how do I delete this and ask again?

Comment: Don't delete it, [edit] it instead to update and add information.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
<name>TaxiRide/name>
```

should be

```
<name>TaxiRide</name>
              ^
```